# Bayes Factor for two groups comparison with unequal variances. Is there an unpooled variances version of the ttestBF R function?

Tags: r, bayesian

The `ttestBF` R function from *BayesFactor* package
allows calculating BF in the comparison of two groups assuming equal variances: under the null hypothesis, the effect size is distributed as a normal centered at 0 with variance calculated from the pooled sample variances.

Is there any R function that defines the standard error as a function of the unpooled variances with degrees of freedom obtained from the *Welch-Satterthwaite* equation?

Is `welchtestBF` implemented anywhere?

Comment: The package `Bolstad`, function `bayes.t.test`. You're looking to use `var.equal = F` in your t-test.

Comment: Thank you Kat, It seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Nevertheles, I am not able to extract BF from bayes.t.test output and I found very few examples of using the package on the web. Do you know how to compute bayes factor from bayes.t.test?